# Error: unknown type name y struct

Tags: array, c, condiciones, struct

### Error: unknown type name y struct

---

El error está en la linea siguiente: `void busqueda(Persona arreglo[], int, char, int, int){`, en ¨Persona", y no se me ocurre cómo arreglarlo

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct Persona {
    char nombre[30];
    int edad;
    float est;
    char sexo;
} Persona_n[10];
void darNumElem(int *);
void busqueda(Persona arreglo[], int, char, int, int){
    printf("\n Nombre  Edad");
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        if(arreglo[i].edad==e){
            for(int j=0; arreglo[i].nombre[j]!='\0'; j++){
                if(arreglo[i].nombre[j]==l && j==p){
                    printf("\n %s, %d", arreglo[i].nombre, arreglo[i].edad);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int n, i, p, e;
    char l;
    darNumElem(&n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n Ingresa cadena \n");
        gets(Persona_n[i].nombre);
        printf("\n Ingresa edad \n");
        scanf("%d", &Persona_n[i].edad);
        printf("\n Ingresa estatura \n");
        scanf("%f", &Persona_n[i].est);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n Ingresa sexo \n");
        Persona_n[i].sexo=getchar();
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    printf("\n ¿Que letra del nombre tiene la persona que desea encontrar? \n");
    scanf("%c", &l);
    printf("\n ¿En que posicion debe estar la letra? \n");
    scanf("%d", &p);
    printf("\n ¿Que edad debe tener la persona \n");
    scanf("%d", &e);
    busqueda(Persona_n, n, l, p, e);
}
void darNumElem(int * n){
        printf("Numero de elementos \n");
        scanf("%d", n);
    }
```

El programa debe guardar los datos en un arreglo de estructuras e imprimir solo el nombre y edad de los datos que cumplan las condiciones; pero para comparar el arreglo nombre con la letra en la posición introducida por el usuario, debo recorrer el arreglo nombre dentro del arreglo Persona_n, ¿Las condiciones de los if son correctas?

```
void busqueda(Persona arreglo[], int, char, int, int){
    printf("\n Nombre  Edad");
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        if(arreglo[i].edad==e){
            for(int j=0; arreglo[i].nombre[j]!='\0'; j++){
                if(arreglo[i].nombre[j]==l && j==p){
                    printf("\n %s, %d", arreglo[i].nombre, arreglo[i].edad);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es la información del compilador:

**11    15  C:\A [Error] unknown type name 'Persona'**

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Tienes que declarar el `struct` y luego usar `struct Persona` para referirte a al `struct` **ya definido.**

Comment: Agrega este codigo antes de la declaracion de `darNumElem`: `typedef struct Persona Persona;`

Comment: El problema radica que no puedes usar `Persona` sin anteponer el `struct`, asi que con `typedef` puedes crear un alias para poder usar `Persona` en vez de `struct Persona`

Answer (score 1):

Sólo necesitas dos cambios en tu código para que sea válida (no necesariamente correcto, pero válido):

En la declaración de la función

```
void busqueda(Persona arreglo[], int, char, int, int){
```

`Persona` no es un tipo de datos. Los tipos de datos se crean usando `typedef`. Lo que tú tienes es una `struct Persona`.

Cuando **defines** una función tienes que ponerle nombre a los parámetros; si no, ¿cómo los accesas?

La declaración correcta es asi:

```
void busqueda(struct Persona arreglo[], int n, char l, int e, int p) {
```

Nota: use los nombres que aparecen sin declarar dentro de la función. Revisa que correspondan.

En cambio, en

```
void darNumElem(int *);
```

no pones nombres porque **no** estas definiendo la función; simplemente dices que existe y que recibe tales parámetros. La definición está en otra parte.

**No usar gets**

Por razones de seguridad (buffer overflow), en lugar de `gets` usa `fgets`. Donde dice:

```
gets(Persona_n[i].nombre);
```

usa

```
fgets(Persona_n[i].nombre, 30, stdin);
```

La función `fgets` está definida así:

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
```

- str: un puntero donde dejaras lo leido.
- n: l tamaño disponible (en bytes).
- stream: desde donde lees.

La función lee un máximo de `n-1` caracteres y le agrega un `0` al final para convertirlo en una cadena valida.